# Invisible artifact from Sketchup model affecting colliders in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, model, artifact, sketchup, collider

I'm getting a weird collider issue after importing an .fbx model from Sketchup into Unity. There's an invisible artifact of some kind on the green platform, which is the model I imported from Sketchup. I've tried disabling different options both in export and import but it doesn't seem to help.  If I use a primitive in place of the imported object, the problem goes away, so I know it's a problem with the model.

[image]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of what the object's physics collider looks like? if you select the object, the physics collider is the green wireframe. Also, include the collider of the wall.

Answer (score 0):

just take the collider off the green table, then add a box collider to it and adjust the dimensions. you dont have to use a mesh collider, and in your case theres no point, because youre calculating a flat surface, so whatever is causing the artifact in the model, you will be better off performances wise(though probably barely enough to measure) to just use a box collider and its 8 points, than a mesh collider with who knows how many.

alternatively, reopen your model in your editing software, and see if you can find what causes the artifact. using a box collider is still the simplest most effective way. even if you need four more colliders for the `walls` of your pool table, timewise you will be ahead.

*edit* at first glance i was thinking billiards. but it appears to be golf, and you are trying to put? my answer is then invalid, as your green will presumably need different slopes and angles, for which you will need a mesh collider. out of curiosity, did you make the mesh convex? if you did, turn it off and try again. if you didnt, turn it on and try again.